# How to calculate value of registers from memory addresses mips

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers

could you explain to me, what the values of $t1,$t2,$t3,$t4 are in hex,  after the program has finished running.
array stars from 0x10010000
thanks

```
.data
A: .word 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
   .text
   la $t2, A
   la $t5, A
   addi $t1,$zero, 0
   addi $t4,$zero, 0
   addi $t2,$t2, 24

   L2:
   lw  $t3, 0($t2)
   add $t4, $t4 ,$t3
   add $t1, $t1, $t3
   add $t1, $t1 ,$t3
   addi $t2, $t2 -4
   bne $t2, $t5 , L2
```

Comment: Use a debugger/simulator to single step the code and watch the registers change. Also, be more specific about which step is unclear. Surely you can follow a few additions?

Comment: i want help with the lw  $t3, 0($t2) and A: .word 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 is array with 0?

Comment: `lw $t3, 0($t2)` loads word from memory into `t3` register. The address from which the word is fetched is calculated as `t2+0`, i.e. the value in register `t2` is used as memory address. Upon first time that `lw` is encountered the CPU, the `t2` contains address `A` plus `24`, which makes it to point at the first byte of word with value `7`. (24 = 6*4, so 6 words from start of `A` are ahead of this `A+24` memory address, memory on MIPS platform is addressed by bytes, so next word starts at +4 address, as word is 32 bits = 4 bytes (1 byte = 8 bits)). (and `lw` loads 4 bytes in group = word)